# What if a view is an empty value while loading it in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building an application which requires loading view dynamically. The value of view is a variable and it depends on what the controller sets it. Sometimes my value is returned as empty or null value, that is I don't want any view to load. But then my code breaks at the same place and half of the screen goes blank. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Show some code so that we can get a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this myself. What I was doing earlier in my view was:

```
$this->load->view($viewname);
```

The value of the viewname used to come from controller as:

```
$data['viewname'] = 'dynamicview'; 
$this->load->vars($data);
```

What I am doing right now is, in my controller:

```
$data['viewname'] = $this->load->view('dynamicview',null,TRUE);
$this->load->vars($data);
```

And now in my view, I simply write:

```
echo $viewname;
```

Actually this passes view as data in the controller and then parses it in the view where we actually print it.
I hope this helps someone out there. Saved my day atleast...

Answer (score 0):

Check for the value in the controller, if the value is empty don't load the view?

```
if($variable== something)
{
    $this->load->view('myView');
} else {
    do something else;
}
```

Comment: What you said is correct but how wise would it be to write logic in the view? Anyways I found a solution for this, I have posted the same as my answer

Comment: What I posted was meant to go in the controller not the view.